# VBA: Error de compilación, calificador no valido VBA

Tags: vba

Estoy realizando una tarea para la universidad y me encuentro con el siguiente ejercicio:

"Cree un macro en VBA el cual usando un ciclo For, en la última hoja del libro a partir de la celda A1 hacia la derecha, hacia abajo y en diagonal llene las celdas con los valores del 1 al 5"

A partir de esto, llegué al siguiente resultado que debería funcionar, pero cuando ejecuto la macro me dice:
Error de compilación: calificador no valido.
¿Donde podría estar mi error?

```
Sub CicloFor()
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    [A1].Select
    Dim x As Byte

    For x = 1 To 5
        ActiveCell.Value = x
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = x.Select
    Next x

    [A1].Select
    For x = 1 To 5
        ActiveCell.Value = x
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = x.Select
    Next x

    [A1].Select
    For x = 1 To 5
        ActiveCell.Value = x
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = x.Select
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Nos facilitaría ayudarte si dejaras el error que te da el compilador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando seleccionar x (x.Select) que lo has definido como Byte y ese método es incorrecto.

No sé si lo que buscas es esto:

```
Sub CicloFor()

    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht = wk.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    contador = 1
        
    For x = 1 To 5
        For y = 1 To 5
            sht.Cells(x, y) = contador
            contador = contador + 1
        Next
        contador = 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias! No me había fijado.

Answer (score 0):

No me había fijado en que escribir x.select me causaba un problema y al final lo corregí así:

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
[a1].Select
Dim x As Byte

For x = 1 To 5
    ActiveCell.Value = x
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next x

[a1].Select
For x = 1 To 5
    ActiveCell.Value = x
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next x

[a1].Select
For x = 1 To 5
    ActiveCell.Value = x
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
Next x
```